# How can i get my list in correct order

Tags: groovy

I have almost got it right but my order will be like this

```
1.1.0.98
1.1.0.65
1.1.0.134
1.1.0.103
```

so it seems that when a third number is on it goes below the second.

code

```
def url = "http://mylink/".toURL().text
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(url)

def mylist = []
         root.data.'content-item'.each{node ->
    mylist << node.resourceURI.text() + node.relativePath.text().getAt(1..-2).replaceAll('/', '-').plus('.nupkg')
}

def result = []
mylist .reverseEach {
result << it
}

result
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: I'm not sure what language that is, but it isn't PowerShell.

Comment: sorry wrong label. Changed to groovy

Comment: Do you have some example XML that shows the problem?  It's hard to answer your question without a workable example we can try

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you're asking, but you can make your code a *lot* simpler...

This should work:

```
def result = root.data.'content-item'.collect { node ->
    node.resourceURI.text() + 
        node.relativePath.text()[1..-2].replaceAll('/', '-') +
        '.nupkg'
}.reverse()
```

no need for `myList` or `reverseEach`

Comment: thx. That was good. The sorting ting is still the same though. I Think it only sorts 1-99 right and then 100- above get below

Comment: Without some example xml to test it, I don't know what you're talking about, sorry :-(